# Showing content on item clicked in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ng-repeat in which there are pairs of two rows. My aim is to show the second row after the first is clicked.

```
<div class="row myClass"
    ng-repeat="sth in sths"
    ng-class="{ cssSthEven: (($index%2) == 0), cssSthOdd: ($index%2)}">
    <div class="row">
        {{sth.name}} {{sth.surname}}
    </div>
    <div class"row">
        {{sth.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have:

[image]

What I wish to have after John Smith is clicked:

[image]

Comment: Any attempts from your side?

Comment: My solution only toggles/hides everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few interesting angularJS docs that could work as a good practice for your example.

Using ng-repeat, odd and even are often something you may use, therefore the directives `ng-class-odd="'odd'"` and `ng-class-even="'even'"`can be used in a `ng-repeat`expression

Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd

For conditionally visibility changes, the directive `ng-show` exists https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

### Possible solution

```
<div class="row myClass"
    ng-repeat="sth in sths"
    ng-class-even="'cssSthEven'" ng-class-odd="'cssSthOdd'">
    <div class="row" ng-click="clicked($index)">
        {{sth.name}} {{sth.surname}}
    </div>
    <div class"row" ng-show="sth.isVisiblie">
       {{sth.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

### In your controller

```
$scope.clicked = function(index){
    $scope.sths[index].isVisiblie = true;
}
```

This last function is guessed, since you did not provide how your sths array look like nor where its initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show and ng-hide directives on item you want to show, 
here is how to 
in your controller set a variable to false and when clicked you will make it true. 
 $scope.show =false;

the use this ng-show=show in html you want to hide and show when clicked.
then use ng-click="show=!show" toggle it when need

here you can find docs